# Zoom into scene using transition - Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hey so I am looking for something similar to in tennis when players challenge a point and the video shows whether the ball was in or out by zooming in really really close to the moment when the ball lands to see whether a fraction was on the line.

I have experimented with using transitions with xScale and yScale but the results I get is strange, almost as if the objects have moved during zooming in. If there was a way to lock in position and then zoom, that would work. The second method I tried is putting the graphics into a display group and then scaling the group. This also results in weird behaviour where the whole group begins moving diagonally across the screen.

Please help as this is confusing me

cheers.

**Objects which will scale:**

```
cloud = display.newImageRect("cloud.png", 419,273)
cloud.anchorY = 0
cloud.anchorX = 0.5
cloud.alpha = 1
cloud.x = display.contentCenterX
cloud.y = display.contentCenterY + 250
physics.addBody(cloud, {isSensor=true})

star = display.newImageRect("Star.png", 78,72)
star.anchorY = 0
star.anchorX = 0.5 
star.alpha = 1
star.name = "Star"
physics.addBody(star, {isSensor=true})
star.x = display.contentCenterX
star.y = display.actualContentHeight - display.actualContentHeight - 100
```

**Scale Function**

```
function scale( event )
   transition.to(star, {time=2000, xScale=1.5, yScale = 1.5})
   transition.to(cloud, {time=2000, xScale=1.5, yScale=1.5})
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you scale an object, it may "move" due to its anchor position, which is the position of the object that is used to position it and also works as its 'anchor' during rotation or scale.

So, you have 2 options:

1) Set the anchor position (obj.anchorX = value , obj.anchorY = value ) to the one that will make your object stays in the position that you want;

2) During the transition, also change its x and y to compensate the moving.

Comment: Hey rsc thanks for the reply. What do you mean in option (1) ? B default I have anchor point set, do I need to set this again during/after scale?

Comment: You don't need to set it again, just to make sure that it has the correct one.

Comment: if u can share the code you are using make it easier for us to fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have updated to OP with some code

Comment: based on your code, do u want to keep the object fixed on the top position?

Comment: Not really. that star will move and wherever it stops, i'd like to zoom in at that position without moving it as it scales. At the moment it moves as it  gets bigger